# Какие варианты принятия оплаты на сайте для физлица можете посоветовать?

Tags: платежи

Суть вопроса: есть проект чемпионата с **платным участием**. Участник может быть из любой страны, но 70% прогнозируется из РФ, еще 20% из Украины и Беларуси. Оплата будет приниматься после регистрации с указанием страны(если это важно). Какие можете посоветовать способы оплаты с учетом того, что возмещение денежных средств должно идти на **расчетный счет физлица в СберБанке**. 
Если с Россией более-менее понятно(эквайринг от Сбера или Яндекс.Кошелек), то как с другими странами(бывшие СССР) и возможными другими странами? Работает ли эквайринг у PayPal(повторюсь: с выплатой на карту физлица Сбера)